Building ReactJS components in a existing AngularJS product
Starting a new project that involves a UI redesign and adding new features to an app that is built in AngularJS v1.9.0 (yes a very old version). The app is in production and being used by many of our big clients.
The end goal is to move away from AngularJS and into ReactJS to align with other teams in the organisation. Due to time constraints, suggestions have been made to build the new features (or components) using ReactJS and integrate it into the existing AngularJS app. Easy said then done!!! :)
Coming from a backend experience and very little exposure to both AngularJS or ReactJS, I am finding it difficult to understand the complexity involved and what challenges it brings
after integration i.e. performance, dependencies, maintainability etc.
The app itself is vast and complex, so will it be advisable to use ReactJS and perhaps add more complexity making the app unstable in the future?

"Coming from a backend experience and very little exposure to both AngularJS or ReactJS" ...you need to either hire a really good frontend engineer, or become one. This can be done but it is a significant challenge even for people with the right expertise, which again you will need to buy or learn. Tread very carefully, your description is sparse but it does not sound to me like you are being set up for success on this project.

I actually did this exact thing once, so i'll try to give some tips. But i have to give a few caveats:

This was like 9 years ago and i havn't used angularjs since, so some of the details are lost to time
I implemented a prototype, got sign off, and then implemented the first few pages in react but i left the team before the transition was complete. So any problems that happened after i left i won't know about.
You describe yourself as having little exposure with both angularjs and react; this is the kind of task should probably be done by someone with good experience in both. If you're not good at react you won't be able to set good patterns for the rest of the team to follow; if you're not good at the legacy project, you won't know what pieces to prioritize.


Ok, with that out of the way, here we go. As you may know, the way to render the top level of a react tree is createRoot and root.render. You give it a single dom element, tell it what react component you want to render, and it will take ownership of the dom element. In a typical react app this is only called once, but there's no reason you can't call it multiple times, with different dom elements.
So our basic design was to create an AngularJs component which just renders a <div>, and then once it's done rendering for the first time (i think that's $onInit, but again i havn't used angularjs in a while), it calls root.render(<TheReactComponent/>), pointing it at the div we just created. The react component then contains the real implementation of the component, putting stuff that matters onto the screen.
These wrapper components can then be scattered throughout the app, everwhere we want to cross over into react-land. A natural spot to do it is on the page level, but it could also be just a section of the page. Our intention was that any new pages we would just write from scratch using react. And when it came time to convert an old page, we would start with a section of the page, then expand outward to a larger section, moving the boundary farther up the tree until it took over the entire page.
I recommend that for simplicity you only make this kind of adapter in one direction. Ie, allow putting react components inside angular ones, but not the other way around.

A few things you'll need to solve:

Passing data across the boundary. You're probably going to have cases where you want to pass data from angular to react, or get notified when something happens in react. To do this you should be able to use react props. When you call root.render you can pass in props, based on what you have in your angular component. And if you need to update these props, you can just call root.render again, passing in the new props (i'd guess you'll want to do this in $onChanges)

Dependency injection. Another form of passing data across the boundary. you may want to have the wrapper component use angularjs's dependency injection to pull in some services or other code that you want to share with react, and then it can perhaps render a react context provider which in turn makes that dependency available to react components.

Routing. Angular and react's approaches to routing are different from eachother. Hopefully they'll play nice, but it probably takes some work. This is something i did not solve in my prototype. Our plan was to use exclusively angular's router until most of the app was in react, and then do a big-bang conversion of all the routing. I wasn't there to know how that worked out.



A couple things that are unavoidable and you will need to decide if it's worth it:

Your bundle size will increase, significantly. React is not a small library, so having two frameworks running side by side will increase the amount of code, which increases load time.
Your app will become more complex and harder to maintain while you're doing this transition. Your team will need to know both frameworks, and until you get the pattern figured out you'll need to debug the interface between the two frameworks.

But if your goal is to switch to another framework (understandable, given what you're using currently), this or something like this may be the only practical approach. This approach can be done incrementally, which makes it much easier to sell to higherups than saying "we need 2 years to rewrite from scratch".
Make sure you have buy-in from the team and the leadership to do this transition. Even if you decide it's the best way to do the transition, it will still not be easy. It will take a while to complete, and abandoning it half way would leave you with a mess.

Thank you so much for explaining in detail and highlighting the crucial bits in solving the transition and also the bits to avoid. I am mainly concerned that we are against time and the transition have been left to be solved by inexperienced devs.
